# HaProxy 1.8 in production

Tags: haproxy

Do you know any high trafic big websites using HaProxy 1.8 in a production environment?
We're still seeing it in the testing repo from Redhat, but wonder if some important websites brought it to production.

Thank you

Comment: We are using it in production at my company. It's had great performance and handled high volume well. We recently switched from the free nginx to get the zero downtime reloads which have been flawless.

Comment: Did you enable http/2 ?

Comment: Yes we did enable h2